# How to get custom headers on left and right pages?

Tags: header-footer

I have got the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{book}

\usepackage[a4paper,width=150mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm,headheight=28pt,bindingoffset=6mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[pagestyles]{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}


\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\bfseries}{}{10pt}{\Huge\thechapter.\quad}
\newpagestyle{mystyle}{
  \sethead[][][\thechapter.\quad\chaptertitle]{\sectiontitle}{}{\thepage}
  \setfoot[][\thepage][]{\thesection~\sectiontitle}{}{\thepage}}


\begin{document}

\pagestyle{mystyle}
\chapter{Introduction}
\lipsum[1-40]

\end{document}
```

It produces a custom header only on even numbered pages. On odd pages it displays the page number. How can I get it to display the custom header (1. Introduction) at central position on both odd and even pages?

Comment: What's the difference with your previous post? Further, I've just updated my answer to this previous post. Did you take a look?

Comment: On odd number there's only the page number because there's  no section in your code, that's all.

Answer (score 2):

To bring the `\sectiontitle` in the Header, you suppose to provide `\section`

Check the below:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{book}

\usepackage[a4paper,width=150mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm,headheight=28pt,bindingoffset=6mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[pagestyles]{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\bfseries}{}{10pt}{\Huge\thechapter.\quad}
\newpagestyle{mystyle}{
  \sethead[][][\thechapter.\quad\chaptertitle]{}{}{\thesection~\sectiontitle}
  \setfoot[][\thepage][]{}{\thepage}{}}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{mystyle}
\chapter{Introduction}
\lipsum[1-5]
\section{H1 for test}
\lipsum[1-15]
\end{document}
```

Hope it helps!